# Sums of consecutive powers of 3 being perfect squares

Tags: elementary-number-theory, summation

I was recently considering the puzzle of finding consecutive (integer) powers of 3 that sum to a square. It's not hard to show that this can be reduced to finding values of $n$ such that

$S_3(n) = \displaystyle\sum_{i=0}^n 3^i\tag*{}$

is either a square or one more than a square. It's not hard to find three such values: $S_3(0) = 1$, $S_3(2) = 4$ and $S_3(5) = 121$. However, I've verified numerically that for no other values of $n$ up to $10,000$ is $S_3(n)$ either a square or one more than a square.

How would one go about either proving that these are the only such values for $n$ or finding other values (other than brute force search, assuming there are more values to find)?

The question could obviously be generalized to bases other than 3. When is

$S_b(n) = \displaystyle\sum_{i=0}^nb^i\tag*{}$

either a square or one more than a square. Here are the results of my experimenting for low values of $b$ and $0<n\le10,000$.

$\begin{array}{c|l}b&n\\\hline2\\3&3^0+3^1 = 2^2\\&3^0+3^1+3^2+3^3+3^4 = 11^2\\4&4^0+4^1 = 2^2+1\\5\\6\\7&7^0+7^1+7^2+7^3 = 20^2\\8&8^0+8^1 = 3^2\\9&9^0+9^1 = 3^2+1\end{array}\tag*{}$

Comment: $S_3(2)$ is $13$, not $4$

Comment: For base $3$, there is no further solution in the range $1\le n\le 10^5$

Comment: It is very likely that you found all solutions for the bases $2$ upto $9$. Upto $n=10^5$, you did not miss any solution.

Comment: It's apparent that you require (or believe) that all powers of $3$, starting with $3^0$ are to be included. But from the English language statement of your question, the example $3^2+3^3=36$ is admitted.

Comment: Adding to my last comment, any number of the form $3^{2n}+3^{2n+1}$.

Comment: Or $3^{2n}+3^{2n+1}+3^{2n+2}+3^{2n+3}+3^{2n+4}$

Comment: @KeithBackman - Yes, the general solution to the original problem allows multiplication of a sum by any even power of 2 (or division by any even power of 2 if the first term is at least 9). However, the general solution can be reduced to finding solutions where $S_3(n)$ (i.e., starting the sum at 1) is either a square or one more than a square. That's why I only asked about that.

Comment: @Ted Hopp  The uncertainty in my thinking goes to your statement that the sum be equal to a square *or a square plus 1* which suggests that you are willing to start your summation index  for series leading to squares at $i=1$ rather than $i=0$. That in turn suggested to me that you would entertain solutions starting at other values of $i$, which I identified after thinking about things over the course of a few minutes.

Comment: @KeithBackman - I see your confusion. The original problem is indeed to find any sum of consecutive powers of 3 that are squares, starting at any power. The general form of such a sum is $3^pS_3(n)$ for some $p$ and $n$. However, if a solution can be found with $p>1$, another solution can be found by dividing by 9. Therefore, without loss of generality, we need only consider $p=0$ and $p=1$. However, $3S_3(n)$ = $S_3(n+1) - 1$, so in the end we only need to find $n$ such that $S_3(n)$ is a square or one more than a square. From there we can easily find all answers to the original problem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We have
$$
\sum_{i=0}^n 3^i = \frac{3^{n+1}-1}{2}
$$

Therefore, if $\sum_{i=0}^n 3^i=a^2$, then we have
$$
3^{n+1} = 1 + 2a^2
$$

It follows from a result of Nagell that this equation has no solutions for $n\ge 2$ except $a=11$ and $n=4$. ($242+1 = 243$). The remaining cases - $n=0$ and $n=1$ - both give rise to easy solutions.

*Note:* Nagell's result is actually stronger, and replaces the '$3$' in the above expression with an arbitrary positive integer $y$: i.e., it states that there is no solution to $y^{n+1}=1+2a^2$ for $n\ge 2$ except $y=3,n=4,a=11$. I don't know if there is an easier proof of this special case.

**Update:** You also asked about the 'one more than a square' case, which we can prove using more elementary means. In this case, we have $\sum_{i=0}^n 3^i = a^2 + 1$ and so

$$
3^{n+1} = 3 + 2a^2
$$

We know that the number $9$ does not divide the right hand side of this equation: indeed, if $a$ is a multiple of $3$, then $2a^2$ is a multiple of $9$ and therefore $3 + 2a^2$ is not a multiple of nine.  Conversely, if $a$ is not a multiple of $3$, then $3+2a^2$ cannot even be a multiple of $3$.

The only possible value of $3^{n+1}$ that is not a multiple of $9$ is $3$ (when $n=0$). From this it follows that $a=0$ too.

*Nagell, Trygve*, Contributions to the theory of a category of Diophantine equations of the second degree with two unknowns, Nova Acta Soc. Sci. Upsal., Ser. IV 16, No. 2, 38 p. (1954). [ZBL0057.28304](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0057.28304).

Comment: There's also the other half of the original problem: sums of consecutive powers of 3 that start with an odd power. Those correspond to $\sum_{i=0}^n 3^i = a^2+1$ (rather than $a^2$).

Comment: @TedHopp I've now answered this question as well.  This time, the methods we use are much simpler.

Comment: Thanks for that. I should have been able to work that last part out for myself.  